# web scraping - using R within a page search

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to collect data for my project, using a website public data http://www.autonews.com/section/searchresults?q=new%20launch%20ford

I have to scrape the results having particular words such as `Ford`, `2005`and `launch`in the title of the news. I want to scrape the entire title as well the main body text from all the pages the query returned (Page 1, 2 , 3 mentioned in the bottom).

In the link provided, I should get the following result,

"Ford Fusion launch disrupted October 24, 2005" and the "body: Ford Motor Co. insists that supply....."

Is it possible to do it using R? Which package would be most useful? Any guidance on the implementation would be very helpful.

Cheers!

PS: Let me know if I am not clear thanks.

Comment: I'm liking `rvest` alot. As long as the website isn't dynamically generated with javascript, it should do just fine.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how you came to the conclusion you're not violating their [Terms and Conditions](http://www.autonews.com/article/20110504/STATIC/110509939).

Comment: @hrbrmstr - If I am able to make my code work, I am going to ask them for permission before I use their data. If they allow me to do the same its fine else, I can use the same methodology using other websites. Any ways I am not going to use their scraped content as a headline display to my website.

Comment: @Chrisss - thanks for the advice, I will look through the snippets and working examples. If you know any good similar work already done. Please let me know. Thanks a lot